# How do I refresh all viewers LIVE from the wordpress admin.

Tags: wordpress, live-streaming, page-refresh

I am creating a live streaming site and 9 out 10 user issues are resolved with a browser refresh.

So... I'm trying to find a way to force refresh all viewers with a click of a button.

However, I want my admins to be the only ones with access to this feature so I want to place this button in the themes admin section.

I have fiddled and read many threads that point towards the "location.window" option. However I am still uncertain as to how to make this happen for all viewers live immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve something like this by setting a timer and polling the server every xx seconds via AJAX. Whenever an admin presses the 'force refresh' button, the browsers will reload the page upon the next 'poll'.

For example;

On the server, a 'token' is stored inside a JSON file;

`token.json`:

```
{currentToken:1039593029484930294820}
```

On each page, a JavaScript is included, polling the server every xx seconds to check the token. If the token has modified, refresh the page;

If an admin wants to force a refresh, the token is invalidated and a new token is generated and saved inside `token.json`. All users still using the old token, should refresh the page.

Example (assuming jQuery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var currentToken;

        var checkToken = function() {
            $.getJSON('/token.json', function(data) {
                if (!currentToken) {
                    // first poll
                    currentToken = data.currentToken;
                    return;
                }

                if (currentToken !== data.currentToken) {
                    // a new token is set by the admin. Reload the page
                    window.location.reload();
                }
           });
        };

        // check if the token is still valid every 2 seconds
        window.setTimeout(checkToken, 2000);

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Going based off what thaJeztah said, with a few modifications...

Create a file called token.json which contains the following:

```
{"currentToken":"1039593029484930294820"}
```

Use the following script, assuming jQuery (1.10.2 worked for me)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentToken_js;
    var checkToken = function() {
        $.getJSON( '/token.json', {
            tags: "currentToken",
            tagmode: "any",
            format: "json"
        }).done(function( data ) {
            if (!currentToken_js) {
                // first poll
                currentToken_js = data.currentToken;
                return;
            }
            if (currentToken_js != data.currentToken) {
                currentToken_js = data.currentToken;
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
        window.setTimeout(checkToken, 2000);
    };
    window.setTimeout(checkToken, 2000);
});
</script>
```

All you have to do is modify the value of currentToken in the token.json file and all instances should refresh.